# Indexing an entire row with `[` as a function

Tags: r

I would like to use `` `[` `` as a function argument in `lapply` to index full rows. It is fairly straightforward to do this with individual elements:

```
lapply( list(iris, mtcars), `[`, 1, 3 )
# [[1]]
# [1] 1.4
#
# [[2]]
# [1] 160
```

However, I can't seem to figure out the prefix equivalent to indexing an entire row of a data frame:

```
lapply( list(iris, mtcars), `[`, 1 )     # Seems to index columns
lapply( list(iris, mtcars), `[`, i=1 )   # ...same?
```

I know I can always define a new function

```
lapply( list(iris, mtcars), function(x) {x[1,]} )   # Desired behavior
```

but I was wondering if there's a way to get the equivalent of `x[1,]` in prefix form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
lapply(list(iris, mtcars), "[", 1, )

[[1]]
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa

[[2]]
          mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4
```

The blank space after `1,` is dedicated to column(s). As you want an entire row, it is blank. If you do:

```
lapply(list(iris, mtcars), "[", 1, 1)
```

it returns:

```
[[1]]
[1] 5.1

[[2]]
[1] 21
```

that is the first row of the first column.

Comment: Whoa. You just blew my mind. Any insight on what's happening under the hood?

Comment: Elaborated it in my post :) Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: I guess the striking part to me is that the missing arguments are faithfully preserved by the `...` dots in `lapply`. It makes sense that they would be; I just hadn't thought about it.

Answer (score 1):

Some explanation on why @tmfmnk's answer works :

The function `[.data.frame` calls the primitive `nargs()` which counts arguments including the empty ones.

The dots `...` can forward empty arguments but usually they end up being forwarded to `list(...)` which would fail. This is not the case here however.

This might make it clearer :

```r
fun1 <- function(x,y) {
  message(sprintf("fun1, missing(y): %s", missing(y)))
  message(sprintf("fun1, nargs(): %s", nargs()))
  invisible()
}
fun1(1)
#> fun1, missing(y): TRUE
#> fun1, nargs(): 1
fun1(1,)
#> fun1, missing(y): TRUE
#> fun1, nargs(): 2
```

```
fun2 <- function(...) {
  message(sprintf("fun2, substitute(alist(...)): %s", 
                  deparse(substitute(alist(...)))))
  message(sprintf("fun2, ...length: %s", ...length()))
  message(sprintf("fun2, nargs(): %s", nargs()))
  fun1(...)
  message("trying `list(...)`")
  list(...)
}
fun2(1)
#> fun2, substitute(alist(...)): alist(1)
#> fun2, ...length: 1
#> fun2, nargs(): 1
#> fun1, missing(y): TRUE
#> fun1, nargs(): 1
#> trying `list(...)`
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1
fun2(1,)
#> fun2, substitute(alist(...)): alist(1, )
#> fun2, ...length: 2
#> fun2, nargs(): 2
#> fun1, missing(y): TRUE
#> fun1, nargs(): 2
#> trying `list(...)`
#> Error in fun2(1, ): argument is missing, with no default
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>